# Не правильно подсчитывает сумму значений элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, счетчики

Приветствую. Есть товары, каждого наименования может быть любое количество (увеличивается динамически с помощью кнопок +/-), пытаюсь собрать общую сумму со всех элементов в виде "сумма руб.", причем вывести в 2ух элементах. Проблема в том, что первоначально (при добавлении одного, двух, трех товаров) в summary все считает правильно, но если начинать увеличивать количество наименовании товаров с помощью кнопки + summary дописывает к итоговой сумме сумму предыдущего товара. Как это можно исправить?

```js
var summary = 0; // при попадании нового товара в корзину происходит обнуление
$('.li').each(function() {

  var $this = $(this);
  var quantity = $this.find(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
  var basePrice = "";
  for (var i = 1; i < quantity.length; i++) {
    basePrice += quantity[i];
  }
  var $input = $this.find(".input-text.qty.text");
  var max = +$input.attr("max");
  var min = +$input.attr("min");

  function updateValue(newValue) {
    var value = +newValue;
    newValue > max && (value = max);
    newValue < min && (value = min);
    var item = value * basePrice;
    console.log(item); //сумма одного элемента
    summary = summary + item;
    console.log(summary); //получаем сумму всех элементов
    $this.find(".amount").text(value * basePrice + " руб");
    $(".summary").text(summary + " руб");
    $("#shopping-button .amount").text(summary + " руб");
    $this.find(".quantity")[0].firstChild.data = value + " × ";
    $input.val(value);
  }

  $this.find(".plus").click(function() {
    updateValue(+$input.val() + 1);
    return false;
  });

  $this.find(".minus").click(function() {
    updateValue(+$input.val() - 1);
    return false;
  });

  $input.click(function() {
    updateValue($input.val());
    return false;
  });
  updateValue(quantity[0]);
});
```

```html
<!-- Считаем сумму с каждого li-->
<div class="li">
  <div class="product-text">
    <span class="quantity">9 × <span class="amount">1.080.000 руб</span></span>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="remove-item" title="Удалить эту позицию">remove</a>
  <div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="100" id="num_count" name="quantity" value="1" title="Кол." class="input-text qty text" size="4">
    <input type="button" value="+1" id="button_plus" class="plus">
    <input type="button" value="-1" id="button_minus" class="minus">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Получить здесь-->
<div class="fixed-bottom">
  <p>Итого..........<span class="summary"><b>416.000</b></span>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- и здесь-->
<li id="shopping-button">
  <a class="shopping-button" href="#">
    <b><span class="amount">1.080.000&nbsp;руб.</span></b>
  </a>
  <!--/ .shopping-button-->
</li>
```

Comment: В чём именно ошибка, что в консоли? Сделайте фиддл, демонстрирующие проблему.

Comment: Напр. синтаксические ошибки: лишняя `};` в 4 снизу строчке. А также `$this` не определён вне ф-ии (5-я снизу строка).

Comment: @Sergiks подправил код и изменил вопрос

Comment: Целиком писать за вас корзину вряд ли кто-то станет. В целом логика такая: у вас есть объекты класса *Товар* с одинаковой логикой внутри. И есть (в вашем коде сейчас отсутствует) *Коллекция* этих Товаров. Коллекция отвечает за общие показатели: тотал сумму, напр.

При удалении / изменении кол-ва любого из товаров, это Товар должен сигналить «наверх», Коллекции, что надо бы пересчитать тоталы.

Comment: @Sergiks писать про какую целиком корзину вы говорите? корзина ведь уже есть и считает для одного элемента. осталось интерполировать это на всех по принципу summary = summary +(value * basePrice) и учесть удаление элемента - вот и все. Затык в том, что логические операции javascript ведь считает иначе, чем тот же php ?